# Update a database record without refreshing a page. ASP VBscript

Tags: ajax, database, asp-classic, vbscript

This requests for help follows a poorly worded request for help earlier (apologies).

I have two asp/vbscript pages.  The second page (containing only <% vbscript %> is called when a form on the first page is submitted.

The code on the second page causes an update to a database record and is as follows (the fields are populated from querystring variables.):

```
    Set MyConn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        MyConn.Open "dsn=xxx;uid=xxx;password=xxx;"
        SQLString = "UPDATE dbo_tbl_printing_tempstore SET " & fieldPrefix & "has_text1 = 'YES', " & fieldPrefix & "text = '" & fieldUpdate & "' WHERE id = " & tempid & ""
        MyConn.Execute(SQLString)
        MyConn.Close
    Set MyConn = Nothing
```

All the form submit does is to cause the database update to happen - nothing else.

The page then response.redirects back to the calling page. This causes a refresh and lot of data on the first page to be lost - this is what I'm trying to avoid.

Can someone please tell me how I can carry out the update without leaving and then refreshing the calling page please?  I've been told Ajax can do this but I have no experience at all of using it.

Many thanks

Comment: Yes, ajax is what you should have a look at. Do some research on Ajax, HTML, and HTTP in general...

Comment: It strikes me that this question is not relevant to JavaScript and should not be tagged as such.

Comment: Home, thanks I will look but I really could do with some help for this one requirement.  I'm sure I'll end up learning Ajax but it's a whole nw thing for me.
Milad Naseri, you are probably correct but as I don't know if there is some sort of javascript/jquery solution it was appropriate to put it in until someone said otherwise

Answer (score 1):

First of all, change your code to use parameters so you will be protected against SQL Injection attack:

```vbscript
Set MyConn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
MyConn.Open "dsn=xxx;uid=xxx;password=xxx;"
SQLString = "UPDATE dbo_tbl_printing_tempstore SET " & fieldPrefix & "has_text1 = 'YES', " & fieldPrefix & "text = ? WHERE id = ?"
Set MyCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set MyCommand.ActiveConnection = MyConn
MyCommand.CommandType = 1
MyCommand.CommandText = SQLString
MyCommand.Parameters.Append(MyCommand.CreateParameter("@text", 200, 1, 0, fieldUpdate))
MyCommand.Parameters.Append(MyCommand.CreateParameter("@id", 3, 1, 0, tempid))
MyCommand.Execute()
MyConn.Close
Set MyCommand = Nothing
Set MyConn = Nothing
```

Having this, the next step is adding hidden frame in the first page:

```html
<iframe id="MyFrame" name="MyFrame" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

And finally simply add `target` to your `<form>` tag like this:

```html
<form action="SecondPage.asp" target="MyFrame">
```

That's it... now the form will be submitted "inside" the hidden frame, will still trigger the database update and won't cause any refresh.

Comment: thanks for this. I'll give this a try and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Shadow Wizard you're a star!.  I can't belive that was so easy.  I've been pulling my hair out trying to learn Ajax etc. Thanks so much!

Comment: Cheers, sometimes all we need is the correct direction. :) If this solved your problem please mark this as Accepted answer by ticking the V icon to the left, same for your other questions.

Comment: Shadow Wizard, can you tell me how I can make function wait for the database update (above) to be completed before it runs?  I also have to do this whilst waiting for a file to be uploaded (this is also call using your 'hidden iFrame' solution.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: What function? ASP or client side?

Comment: Sorry, javascript function which simply changes the background-image of a div.  Presently the div gets updated before the fie upload (and db update) on the asp page gets time to finish.  The form submits through the iframe to the asp page.  It works ok now but I have to bring up an alert which I have to wait to 'ok' when I'm certain the sending has finishes - which is not acceptable.

Comment: For this you'll have to use full scale AJAX.. google for "jQuery AJAX" for the most simple way I know.